# Adaptive Cards render on skype and emulator, but not web chat

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have a added a few Adaptive Cards to my bot. They render perfectly in the emulator and, when deployed, render perfectly in Skype and Slack. However, in the web chat, I get the following response instead of the rendered card:

```
[File of type 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive']
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be? I'm uncertain how to troubleshoot when the functionality works in all the other environments.

I'm use the Node version of the bot framework.

Comment: This PR is tracking progress on AdaptiveCards support in the Web Chat control: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/471

Comment: Thanks @EricDahlvang, much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the WebChat "Channel" configured via the Bot Portal at https://dev.botframework.com? Or did you deploy the open source version of the WebChat control from: [Microsoft/WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Answer (score 1):

As of 6/12/17, the Bot Framework WebChat open source module does not support Adaptive Cards.

You can track the in-progress work here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/471